# Magento Reports: No records found

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

I got no records found in any dates of any of the following like sales, invoiced, orders, products etc. I am not understanding why it shows no records in csv.

Please anybody tell me the functonality of reports section to make it work properly.

Thanks